# unable to see the BCC field when sending an email via Salesforce

Tags: administration

I am unable to see the BCC field when I am sending an email from Salesforce.com, the field is missing form the page layout strangely, is there a way of getting this back?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context and maybe a screenshot to help the stack folks understand exactly what you are referencing? Is this an email that is auto generated from a workflow rule? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This field is automatically disabled when ["Compliance BCC Email"](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_compliancebcc.htm&language=en_US) is enabled in the organization.

Comment: The reason why is explained here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpAmAAK "For compliance reasons you want to store a copy of the email by bcc'ing another address. If you allowed users to add bcc addresses, you would not be able to see who was BCC'ed and therefore you would not be in compliance."